# how to create an explianation for some text, line and picture even ,and how to align the text

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I can create a color table, but now I want to add some explanation to this table like below picture

[image]

Should I use `tikz` or only table feature? Can anyone give me a start point?

Here is my table code:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=x11names,compress]{beamer}

\usepackage{xcolor, colortbl}
\usepackage{makecell}

\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.85}

\begin{document} 

\begin{frame}{I$^{2}$C contd}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\cellcolor{Gray}S & \cellcolor{Gray}SLAVE ADDRESS & \cellcolor{Gray}R/W  & A & \cellcolor{Gray}DATA & A & \cellcolor{Gray}DATA & A/A & \cellcolor{Gray}P \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I found one method to do this and here are the output and code:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=x11names,compress]{beamer}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.85}

\begin{document} 

\begin{frame}{I$^{2}$C contd}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\hspace*{-1.5em}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[gray] (0,0) grid (12,6);
    \foreach \x in {0,1,...,12}
            \draw (\x cm,1pt) -- (\x cm,-1pt) node[anchor=north] {$\x$};
    \foreach \y in {1,2,...,6}
        \draw (1pt,\y cm) -- (-1pt,\y cm) node[anchor=east] {$\y$};

    %draw data structure
    \draw [fill=Gray] (0,5.5)    rectangle (1,6)    node[pos=.5] {S};
    \draw [fill=Gray] (1,5.5)    rectangle (4.5,6)  node[pos=.5] {SLAVE ADDRESS};
    \draw [fill=Gray] (4.5,5.5)  rectangle (5.5,6)  node[pos=.5] {R/$\overline{W}$};
    \draw             (5.5,5.5)  rectangle (6,6)    node[pos=.5] {A};
    \draw [fill=Gray] (6,5.5)    rectangle (7.5,6)  node[pos=.5] {DATA};
    \draw             (7.5,5.5)  rectangle (8,6)    node[pos=.5] {A};
    \draw [fill=Gray] (8,5.5) rectangle (9.5,6) node[pos=.5] {DATA};
    \draw             (9.5,5.5) rectangle (11,6) node[pos=.5] {A/$\overline{A}$};
    \draw [fill=Gray] (11,5.5) rectangle (11.5,6) node[pos=.5] {P};

    %draw example
    \draw [fill=Gray] (0.5,3) rectangle (1,3.5);
    \draw             (0.5,2) rectangle (1,2.5);

    %draw line
    \draw (5,5.3) -- (5,4.5);
    \draw (6,5.3) -- (6,4.5) -- (6.5,4.5);
    \draw (11,5.3) -- (11,4.5) -- (10.5,4.5);

    %add text
    %\coordinate [label={[blue]above:`0'(write)}] (RW) at (5,4);
    %\coordinate [label={[blue]above:`0'(data transferred \\())}] (RW) at (8.5,4);
    \node [blue, align=center, above] at (5,4) {`0'(write)};
    \node [blue, align=center, above] at (8.5,4) {data transferred \\(n bytes + ACK)};
    \node [red, align=left, above] at (2.8,3) {from master to slave};
    \node [red, align=left, above] at (2.8,2) {from slave to master};
    \node [red, align=left, above] at (8, 3) {A$=$ACK (SDA LOW)};
    \node [red, align=left, above] at (8, 2.5) {$\overline{A}=$NAK (SDA HIGH)};
    \node [red, align=left, above] at (7, 2) {S=START};
    \node [red, align=left, above] at (7, 1.5) {P=STOP};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

it output like:
[image]
However, what is the problem of the text with red color? I already used `align=left` or `right` or `center`, all of them output the same.

I changed my code to:

```
\node [red, align=left, above] at (2.8,3) {from master to slave};
\node [red, align=left, above] at (2.8,2) {from slave to master};
```

it can output correct for above two, but why???? How about right text, how to align them???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd personally do the square nodes using `chains` and with a condition for the filling.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[xcolor=x11names,compress]{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}


\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning, chains}

\tikzset{
    box/.style={draw, text centered, minimum size=2em},
    sqarr/.style={to path={-- ++(0,-8mm)  -| (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes},pos=.25}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{I$^{2}$C contd}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\hspace*{-1.5em}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily, shorten <= 1mm, shorten >= 1mm]
\begin{scope} [start chain, node distance=-\pgflinewidth, every node/.style={fill=gray!50}]  
    \foreach \name [count=\xi starting from 0] in {%
        S,
        SLAVE ADDRESS, 
        R/\={W},
        A,
        DATA, 
        A,
        DATA,
        A/\={A},
        P}{%
        \pgfmathparse{\xi>2 && mod(\xi,2)}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=0
            \node[box, on chain] (n\xi) {\name\vphantom{R/\={W}}};
        \else
            \node[box, fill=white, on chain] (n\xi) {\name\vphantom{R/\={W}}};
        \fi
    }
\end{scope}

\draw (n2.south) --++ (0,-8mm) node[below, font=\footnotesize] {'0' (write)};
\draw[sqarr] (n3.south east) to node[text width=2.5cm, yshift=-.3\baselineskip, inner xsep=0, text centered, fill=white, font=\footnotesize] {data transferred \\(n bytes + ACK)} (n7.south west);

\node[box, font=\footnotesize, fill=gray!50, minimum size=1em, below=2cm of n0, label={right:from master to slave}] (d1) {};
\node[box, minimum size=1em, below=2.5cm of n0, label={right:from slave to master}] {};

\node[text width=4.5cm,font=\footnotesize, anchor=north west] at (d1.north-|n3) {
        A = acknowledge (SDA LOW)\\
        \={A} = acknowledge (SDA HIGH)\\
        S = START condition\\
        P = STOP condition

}; 
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: when I compile the code, it shows that `! I can't find file `tikzlibraryarrows.meta.code.tex.` what package do I need?

Comment: @HowChen make sure your Tex distribution is up to date. :) but I think you can safely remove that library because it's not used in the code I think.

Comment: thanks you! may i know what does `\pgfmathparse{\xi>2 && mod(\xi,2) ? int(0):int(1)}` mean?

Comment: @HowChen Sure, basically two conditions are set. During the `foreach`, only values above 2 are considered (3,4,5,6,...). `mod(\xi,2)` is modular arithmetic is applied, so the result is either `0` or `1`. The rest of the line basically is the value given to `\pgfmathresult`. So after that I can test this value with the `if` statement, and apply the different coloring depending on the value, letting you color the nodes in an alternate fashion.

Comment: Although, that command can be further simplified. I slightly changed the code.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest way would be to include all lines inside the same node with left alignment. This is what I've done in following code, which also show how to use `nodes` and node `rectangle+node` to draw the frame.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=x11names,compress]{beamer}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.85}

\begin{document} 

\begin{frame}[fragile]{I$^{2}$C contd}
Follow figure shows a master writes data to slave with 7-bits address:
\medskip
{\par\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[field/.style={draw, minimum height=5mm, outer sep=-\pgflinewidth, fill={#1}, inner ysep=0pt},
    field/.default={Gray},]

    \begin{scope}[node distance=0pt]
    \node[field, minimum width=1cm] (S) {S};
    \node[field, right=of S] (SA) {SLAVE ADDRESS};
    \node[field, right=of SA, label={[label distance=5mm, blue, name=label1]-90:0 (write)}] (RW) {R/$\overline{\text{W}}$};
    \node[field=white, right=of RW] (A1) {A};
    \node[field, right=of A1] (D1) {DATA};
    \node[field=white, right=of D1] (A2) {A};
    \node[field, right=of A2] (D2) {DATA};
    \node[field=white, right=of D2] (AA) {A/$\overline{\text{A}}$};
    \node[field, right=of AA] (P) {P};
    \end{scope}
    \draw[shorten <=1mm, shorten >=0mm] (RW)--(label1);
    \draw[shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] (A1.south east)--(A1.south east|-label1)-|(AA.south east) node[pos=.25, align=center, blue, fill=white] {data transferred \\(n bytes + ACK)};

    \node[draw, fill=Gray, minimum size=5mm, label={[name=label2]0:from master to slave}, below=1.5cm of S] (fmts) {};
    \node[draw, minimum size=5mm, label=0:from slave to master, below= 5mm of fmts] (fstm) {};
    \node [align=left, anchor=north west] at (fmts.north-|A1.west) {A = ACK (SDA LOW)\\$\overline{\text{A}}$ = NACK (SDA HIGH)\\S = START\\P = STOP};
\end{tikzpicture}\par}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]